# libgdx input method not called

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a screen class which sets the input processor to the stage class `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(gameStage);`, and my stage class implements `inputProcessor` `public class GameStage extends Stage implements InputProcessor`. The input methods in my stage class are not called and I can't figure out why. I tested it with this method

```
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    batch.begin();
    font.draw(batch, "text", 200, 50);
    batch.end();
    return super.touchDown(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);
}
```

But the text is not drawn, when I try it with `Gdx.input.isTouched()` in the act method, it does work.

Thanks

EDIT: All the code

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {
        private Game game;
        private GameStage gameStage;
        private OrthographicCamera camera;
        private Viewport viewport;

        private Box2DDebugRenderer renderer;

        public GameScreen(Game game) {
            this.game = game;
            this.camera = new OrthographicCamera();
            this.viewport = new ScreenViewport(camera);
            this.gameStage = new GameStage(viewport);
            this.renderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(gameStage);
        }

        public OrthographicCamera getCamera() {
            return this.camera;
        }

        @Override
        public void show() {

        }

        @Override
        public void render(float delta) {
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(247/255.0f, 247/255.0f, 247/255.0f, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            gameStage.act();
            renderer.render(gameStage.getWorld(), camera.combined);
            gameStage.draw();
        }

        @Override
        public void resize(int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public void pause() {

        }

        @Override
        public void resume() {

        }

        @Override
        public void hide() {

        }

        @Override
        public void dispose() {

        }
    }
```

Stage class:

```
public class GameStage extends Stage {
    private World world;
    private Player player;
    private BitmapFont font;

    private Box2DDebugRenderer renderer;

    public GameStage(Viewport viewport) {
        super(viewport);
        font = new BitmapFont();
        setUpWorld();
    }

    public void setUpWorld() {
        world = WorldUtils.createWorld();
        player = new Player(WorldUtils.createPlayer(world));
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        super.draw();

        getBatch().begin();
        font.draw(getBatch(), "Position: X=" + player.getX() + " Y=" + player.getY(), 200, 50);
        getBatch().end();
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta) {
        super.act(delta);
        world.step(1 / 300f, 6, 2);
    }

    public World getWorld() {
        return this.world;
    }

    public Player getPlayer() {
        return this.player;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        player.move();
        super.touchDown(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        return super.touchDragged(screenX, screenY, pointer);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return super.touchUp(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);
    }
}
```

Player class:

```
public class Player extends Actor{
    private Body body;

    public Player(Body body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public void move() {
        body.applyForceToCenter(50000, 200, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Stage is an InputProcessor then what do you mean by `my stage class implements inputProcessor` ? Add some more code

Comment: @AbhishekAryan i added the code

Comment: Is stage actually the scene2d Stage class? Because if you use a stage why not use actors? And if that is the case as @AbhishekAryan suggests, `implements inputprocessor` is redundant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't draw inside your input handlers. Just store the coordinates. It's not working because you're trying to draw outside of the game loop. Also return false not the parent method, when you return true the input processor calls all the other matched input handlers. Something like this should do it.

```
boolean touched;
void draw(Batch batch)
    if(touched){
        batch.begin();
        font.draw(batch, "text", 200, 50);
        batch.end();
    }
}
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int      
pointer , int button) {
    super.touchDown(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);
    touched = true;
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int      
pointer , int button) {
    super.touchUp(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);
    touched = false;
    return false;
}
```

Edit: Also remove `implements InputProcessor` The stage class already implements that class so you don't have to. This is probably what causing you handlers to be ignored. You're set input processor of the parent class as main handler but you're override the input handlers of interface not the parent so they aren't being seen.

Edit 2: Try implementing InputProcessor and not extending Stage.

```
public class GameStage InputProcessor {
    private Stage stage;
    private InputMultiplexer input;
    private World world;
    private Player player;
    private BitmapFont font;

    private Box2DDebugRenderer renderer;

    public GameStage(Viewport viewport) {
        stage = new Stage(viewport);
        font = new BitmapFont();
        setUpWorld();
        input = new InputMultiplexer();
        input.addProcessor(this);
        input.addProcessor(stage);
    }

    public void setUpWorld() {
        world = WorldUtils.createWorld();
        player = new Player(WorldUtils.createPlayer(world));
        stage.addActor(player)
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        stage.draw();

        getBatch().begin();
        font.draw(getBatch(), "Position: X=" + player.getX() + " Y=" + player.getY(), 200, 50);
        getBatch().end();
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta) {
        stage.act(delta);
        world.step(1 / 300f, 6, 2);
    }

    public World getWorld() {
        return this.world;
    }

    public Player getPlayer() {
        return this.player;
    }

    public InputAdapter getInput(){
        return this.input;
    }

    public Stage getStage(){
        return this stage;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        player.move();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Touch handling is done right before rendering and is done all on the same thread. So in theory it should work. However it is not at al good practice.

Comment: Agreed, it's not issue. The solution is actually the edited part of my answer. If `implements InputProcessor` is removed it will work.

Comment: it wouldn't happen to be flashing the text for a second than disappearing would it?

Comment: @GeoffTaylor not but the method is being called, I moved the drawing of the text to a different method that gets called when touchDown gets called, the same as the first answer

Comment: try using a different handler other than `touchDown()` try `touchDragged()` instead

Comment: can you show the code where you set the input processor?

Comment: I do it in the constructor of my screen class: `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(gameStage);`, I tried applying force to the player(which is just a square) when touchDown is called but the player is not moving, and getX on the player actor is showing the wrong coordinates, but that's a different problem

Comment: do you call the parent class constructor in your child class?

Comment: Does the Player extend Actor?

Comment: @GeoffTaylor yes it does, I put the code in my question

Comment: put `this.addActor(player);` in `setupWorld()`

Comment: try using edit 2: as your GameStage class and set input processor like this. `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(gameStage.getInput());`

Comment: @GeoffTaylor i did forget to add the player to the stage. What do you mean by edit 2?

Comment: @GeoffTaylor thank you but I really think I missed something because some time ago I tried making another game and I did it sort of the same way, I probably made a very simple mistake since I'm still a beginner with libgdx and I would really like to know what I did wrong

Comment: No problem, this actually made me open a couple of old LibGDX project I haven't finished so this worked out for me too. I would recommend scrapping the Box2D portion of the code until you got the Scene2D stuff up and running.

Comment: @GeoffTaylor just letting you know that everything works, turns out the force I was applying was too small to notice.

Comment: Good, so Box2D was the problem not the input handling?

Comment: @GeoffTaylor Yes indeed, one last thing, do you happen to know how to decelerate a body? Because now when the force is applied it keeps going, but I want it to stop after a second or so. This is what I'm doing now `dir` is the direction in which the player needs to go `body.applyLinearImpulse(dir, body.getWorldCenter(), true);`

Comment: for you particular character I'm not sure, but try `body.applyLinearImpulse(-dir, body.getWorldCenter(), true);` and it may do the trick. Or just place `body.applyLinearImpulse(dir, body.getWorldCenter(), true);` in `touchDragged()`instead of `touchDown()`

Comment: @GeoffTaylor but when should i apply the opposite? Because if I do it in the move method the force gets canceled instantly. The player is just a box with density set to `0.00001f`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow the stage to respond to user input as well as respond to user input yourself you need to use an input [multiplexer](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputMultiplexer.html).

```
InputMultiplexer multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
multiplexer.addProcessor(myStage); // allows stage actors to respond to user input
multiplexer.addProcessor(new MyGameInputProcessor()); // allows you to repond to user actions
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);
```

Comment: No only the stage should respond to input but the input methods in the stage class are not getting called

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you're doing in this way :

```
public class GdxTest extends Game  {

    MyStage myStage;

    @Override
    public void create() {

        myStage =new MyStage();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(myStage);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        myStage.draw();
        myStage.act();
    }
}
```

And `MyStage` class

```
public class MyStage extends Stage {

    BitmapFont font;

    public MyStage(){
        font=new BitmapFont();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

        Gdx.app.log("MyStage","Inside touchDown method");
        drawText();

        return super.touchDown(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);
    }

    @Override
    public void act() {
        super.act();

        //if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        //    drawText();
        //}
    }

    public void drawText(){
        getBatch().begin();
        font.draw(getBatch(), "text", 200, 50);
        getBatch().end();
    }
}
```

According to you : text is not drawing when you're calling `drawText()` from `touchDown(..)` method but if you're calling it from `act()` method, you're getting Text on Screen.

**Reason why text not rendering :**

Whenever you touch screen `drawText()` method called from `touchDown(..)` method but that will be cleared by next `render()` call so you got noting on screen but on the other hand If you call  `drawText()` from `act()` method that actually called by `render()` method of `ApplicationListener` so text draw after clearing the frame buffers and setting the color buffer.

**Solution :**

You need to call `drawText()` on each render call so  override `draw()` method of `MyStage` and  call `drawText()` using flag.

```
boolean drawText;

@Override
public void draw() {
    super.draw();

    if(drawText) {
       drawText();
    }
}
```

and change flag value in `touchDown(..)` method

```
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    drawText=true;

    return super.touchDown(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);
}
```

---

Two recommendation :

1. `Stage` class already implement `InputProcessor` by his adapter class so need to implement again.
2. `Stage` class having own private batch reference so no need to create your own, you can use `getBatch()` method.

Comment: I've removed the redundant implement inputProcessor and the extra spritebatch and moved the text to a different method and it's still not working